# Ошибка установки WSL

Tags: windows, wsl, windows-11, wsl2

При установке выходит ошибка

```
Операция развертывания была заблокирована из-за ограничений политики для каждого семейства пакетов, ограничивающей развертывания приложений на несистемном томе. 
Согласно политике, это приложение должно быть установлено на системный диск, но он не является используемым по умолчанию диском. 
В параметрах хранилища назначьте системный диск используемым по умолчанию расположением сохранения нового содержимого и повторите попытку установки.
```

В параметрах хранилища по умолчанию стоит системный диск. Не пойму на что он тогда еще ругается.

Answer (score 0):

тоже самое сообщение на **wsl --update**

в событиях windows можно найти такое:

```
Развертывание пакета MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForLinux_2.1.5.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe в томе E: завершилось сбоем, так как развертывания приложений в несистемные тома заблокированы для семейства этого пакета.
```

Но совершенно не понятно почему там всплыл диск E: и как его поменять на системный C:

Последние сообщения можно еще посмотреть через PowerShell

```
Get-Appxlog
```

Я проблему решил установкой апдейта вручную
https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi

но при запуске **wsl --update** ошибка остается

Comment: В общем спасло отключение диска E: в моем случае (просто в диспетчере дисков убираем все буквы, назначенные на диск). Дальше wsl --update отработал нормально. И все остальное заработало тоже как должно.